# forward declaration of struct DIR

Tags: c++, c, include

I somehow messed up the [includes](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=245), but weren't able to actually find the error:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLOG(x) printf(x)
#define PLOG(x,y) printf(x,y)
#else
#define DLOG(x)
#define PLOG(x,y)
#endif

harddrive::Results* harddrive::search_for(char* start,char* target,char** ignore,int size) {
PLOG("work directory: %s",start);
DIR* curr_dir = opendir(start);
Results* local = new Results;

if(!curr_dir) {
    printf(" opendir() failure, probably no real directory: %s",start);
    errno = 0;
    return NULL;
}

struct dirent* elem;
while( (elem = readdir(curr_dir)) ) {
    //form URI
    char* uri = form_uri(start,curr_dir->d_name); //here is the actual error
    struct stat st;
    lstat(elem->d_name,&st);
    if( S_ISDIR(st.st_mode) ) {
        if( !do_ignore(uri,ignore,size) )
            local = merge(local,search_for( form_uri(start,elem->d_name), target,ignore,size));
    } 
    else if( S_ISREG(st.st_mode) ) { //this is line 41
```

Compiler output:

```
Directory.cpp: In function ‘harddrive::Results* harddrive::search_for(char*, char*, char**, int)’:
Directory.cpp:34:38: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct DIR’
/usr/include/dirent.h:128:16: error: forward declaration of ‘struct DIR’
```

€:I am sorry for the inconvenience but i pasted an old error code, before I started switching around lines, but now it is correct.

Comment: Can we see line 41? That's where the error is.

Comment: I suspect you've written `DIR` somewhere instead of `DIR*`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I messed up the copy paste but I now edited it and marked the line

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess that this part of the code is C-like but as the project as a whole is c++ I figured putting both would be correct

Comment: If you are only using `lstat` to check file type, have you checked that the `dirent` structure doesn't contain a `d_type` field?

Comment: @MikeSeymour well I am sure that it is, but it was (I am sorry for this) the wrong console I copied the error code out, so I made a final edit which now makes sense, as that is the first use of any element of the struct

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the hint, I didn't know of that feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curr_dir->d_name` should be `elem->d_name`.

As the error says, you're incorrectly trying to dereference a pointer to the opaque type `DIR`.

Comment: thanks, yes that was the actual error, I must have misread the given tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

DIR* is an opaque handle, you can't access its internals. You probably meant to access `elem` instead of `curr_dir`

i.e. change

```
form_uri(start,curr_dir->d_name);
```

to

```
form_uri(start,elem->d_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dirent.h says:
/* This is the data type of directory stream objects.
   The actual structure is opaque to users.  */
typedef struct __dirstream DIR;
```